# Loop until it gets to empty database field

Tags: php

this code works:

```
$i=1;
require('db.php');
$query = "SELECT own".$i." FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

So i try to put it into loop but it is not working. I get only the first result.
Is it even possible to do it that way?

```
while (isset($row['own'.$i])) {
require('db.php');
$query = "SELECT own".$i." FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo $row['own'.$i];
 $i++;
}
```

Also I use the above code to make first check before the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are always selecting only `SELECT own1`.

You need `foreach` instead of `while`

```
require('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"; // SQL Injection HERE!
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach ($rows as $row)) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: i found solution that fits my needs, i check in the loop after each request with if and if its empty it breaks. I need to keep this  "own".$i.  variables because i use them on many spots and don't wanna rewrite so much